# How to access a class attribute using another variable?

Tags: python

```
class myclass:
  ab="python"
  bc="pyspark"
  de="sql"
  ef="azure"
```

```
case 1:
print(myclass.ab)  #output: python
```

```
case 2:
x="ab"
myclass.x          #error: type object 'myclass' has no attribute 'x'
```

How do I access class variable '**ab**' with the help of another variable '**x**'?

Comment: Have a look into the `__getattribute__` dunder method, or the `getattr` builtin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function:

```
>>> x = "ab"
>>> getattr(myclass, x)
'python'
```